# Ruby - regex to return font-face urls in a file

Tags: ruby, regex

im trying to parse a javascript file to return font-face urls.

the file look like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AlfaSlab';
  iesrc: url('/lib/assets/themes/ek/skins/default/alfaslabone-regular-webfont.eot');
  url('/lib/assets/themes/ek/skins/default/alfaslabone-regular-webfont.woff')
```

i want to grab all font links with file extensions (eot,woff,svg,otf)

i came up with this regex `/(\/lib\/.*?\/.*?\.(eot|woff|ttf|svg))/` but its returning also the file extensions (because the () in the file extensions)

in ruby im doing this `files.map {|file| File.read(file).scan(regex)} #=> ['/lib/assets/themes/ek/skins/default/alfaslabone-regular-webfont.eot','eot','/lib/assets/themes/ek/skins/default/alfaslabone-regular-webfont.woff','woff']`

how can i fix the regex to only return the file path instead of the file path + file extension in 2 array elements, thanks :)

#### EDIT:

i want to return the whole path with the file extension, `['/lib/assets/themes/ek/skins/default/alfaslabone-regular-webfont.eot','/lib/assets/themes/ek/skins/default/alfaslabone-regular-webfont.woff']` should be the match.. thanks for your time

Comment: Did you try to move the last ')' like this: **/(\/lib\/.*?\/.*?)\.(eot|woff|ttf|svg)/**

Comment: i want to match the whole path with file extension, this is the result of that regex http://rubular.com/r/AYDMfMDUAH, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite your regex:

```
/([\w\-\/]+\.(?:eot|woff|ttf|svg))/
```

- `[\w\-\/]` defines a set of characters:

  - `\w` word character, i.e. letter (`a-z`, `A-Z`), number (`0-9`) and underscore (`_`)
  - `\-` hyphen (`-`)
  - `\/` slash (`/`)
- `+` means one or more of these characters
- `\.` is the dot before the file extension
- `(eot|woff|ttf|svg)` is the file extension
- `?:` tells the regex engine to *not* generate a *backreference* for this capturing group

Comment: that matches the url without the file extension http://rubular.com/r/eHEb6LBtA4, i want to include the file extension, i added more info in the question, thanks

Comment: that works, could you please explain how this regex works, i'm such a noob when comes to regular expressions. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your comments I think this long regex will do the work. Because, as you said, enclosing all the possible extensions within "( )" will always create a second array element

```
/(\/lib\/.*?\/.*?\.eot|\/lib\/.*?\/.*?\.woff)|\/lib\/.*?\/.*?\.ttf|\/lib\/.*?\/.*?\.svg)/
```

I am not Ruby expert, but you can generalize a little bit more by 
defining a variable

```
$v = "\/lib\/.*?\/.*?\."
$m = "("+$v+"eot|"+$v+"woff|"+$v+"ttf|"+$v+"svg)"
Regexp.new $m
```